# How to find threshold voltage of an NMOS with BSIM3v3 model in LTSPICE

Tags: voltage, ltspice, nmos

I want to determine the threshold voltage of an NMOS from a bvsim3v3 model in LTSPICE(Not a specific one I'm asking generally for this model). I can't get it directly from the parameters so I want to know how to. It doesn't have to be the exact value, I know it can be changeable but a good approach would be sufficient for me.

One way I thought of is to obtain it from the drain current equation. I set Vgs, W and L myself and measure the drain current with simulation. So this leads to a sub-question: How can I obtain oxide capacitor(Cox) and mobility from the model parameters?

Comment: There's a `Vto` parameter, specified as "zero bias threshold voltage". But, what `Vgs` are you referring to? Do you mean the one where it is specified as `IC=VGS`? If so, that's only to be used as initial condition for `.uic`.

Comment: Ok, I think Vto is the answer to me, thank you. According to this equation: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/1735bd11304d6db8538a136860ea2b659492919d second addend goes zero because source and bulk are shorted right? Then we have Vt=Vto left.
About Vgs; I only mentioned that as an extra information about the drain current Id equation. I referred to regular gate-to-source voltage, nothing significant. Doesn't relate to the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @a concerned citizen mentioned, the parameter to be looked is `Vto` at first. According to equation of `Vt`, it gives the basic threshold voltage where source and bulk are shorted(`VSB=0`):

[image: Vt]

Additionally, *Bsim3v3 User's Manual* provides more detailed information about this topic:
http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/external-documents/models/bsim330_manual.pdf 
At the end of *Appendix A(nI-1. and nI-2.)* and beginning of *Appendix B* the necessary equations can be found.

Answer (score 3):

Ground the source, connect the drain to the gate, and feed the drain with a constant current source set to the current value at which you want to know the threshold voltage.

For example:

In Circuitlab this shows a threshold voltage of 4.01V which is actually on the high side of allowable spec.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUOXv4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is indeed what I would do also. For a very large powerfet like the IRF530, that Id = 250 uA is very appropriate. For a smaller MOSFET like used deep inside a chip, I would use a much smaller current like 100 nA even !

Comment: I think I didn't fully understand. How do we specify the current source value? And do we measure the voltage at the gate?

Comment: You measure it with the SPICE simulation by reading the voltage at the gate/drain net. The current is what *you* define as the drain current at the threshold voltage. As @FakeMoustache says, on a chip, you might use 100nA. I picked 250uA because that is the drain current at which Vt is defined on the particular IRF530 MOSFET datasheet I was comparing it against.

Comment: So this method is valid if the drain current at threshold voltage is known right? I was actually asking about a transistor, of which you only know the spice model, not a commercial one that you have a datasheet about.